# is it wrong to malloc a global variable inside a function?

Tags: c++, global-variables, malloc

I have two 'simple' questions in C++.

1- I want to make a variable shared by some methods in a class, so what i am doing is declaring the variable in the header file and make it global to the class. Hence, all methods will have access to it. Is this the right way of doing it ?

2- Following my first point, if i declare variable `N` as `double *N` in the header. Then inside one of my methods, i do

```
N = (double*) malloc (sizeof(double)*50);
```

I know that `N` will have a memory allocation inside the function. My question is: is this memory reserved only inside the function or it stays for the global `N` all the time ?

If the memory won't be reserved for `N`, then this method wouldn't be a good method, as the system might overwrite the values of `N` later during the program.

Please kindly advice, Thank you

EDIT: Thank you all for the input and for editing my question. Apparently i mistakenly called my variable as global while it is actually a class member. I thought this declaration is called global since the variable is global for the methods inside the class. Hope i ask a 'smarter' question next time :)

Comment: Posting some code examples to clarify your question would be helpful for those trying to answer.

Comment: Can someone edit the question to solve the formatting ? The `*` is there, but not between backward quotes.

Comment: Is this pointer (or variable) `N` a member of the class or not?

Comment: When you mean global to the class, you mean `static` ?

Comment: @mcnemesis I with edits that change semantics, especially if the question was posted by a new user. He needs to see this himself and edit. Would you agree to a rollback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clear things up a bit. Assuming this is in header `members.h`:

```
extern double a;     // this is a "global" variable declaration. It needs a definition.

class B {
  double c;          // this is a data member. There will be one in each object of class B
  static double * d; // this is a static data member. There will be a single one for
                     // all objects of class B. It needs a definition.
public:
  void f() { c = 1.0; a = 3.0; }           // A member function can access both static and
                                           // plain data members, as well as globals.
  static void g() { d = new double(2.0); } // A static member function can only access
                                           // static data members and globals.
};
```

Note that variables/data members like `a` or `c` do not require explicit allocation. On the other hand `d` does, because it is a pointer. Note also that in C++ you use `new()` rather than `malloc()`.

This is source file `members.cpp`:

```
#include "members.h"

double a; // Definition of global a

double * B::d;  // Definition for static member d

B b1;     // Static instance of class B

int main() {
  B b2;      // Local instance of class B
  b1.f();    // Calling member function f() on b1
  b2.f();    // Calling member function f() on b2
  B::g();    // Calling static member function g()
}
```

I hope I've been clear enough and covered your doubts.

Answer (score 2):

1. No, avoid globals. Find the right scope and encapsulation for your variable. Put it there.
2. If you declare something as `double` and try to assign a pointer to it, nothing is going to happen. Your code is simply not going to compile. I assume you are talking about a global `double*`. You'd need to `malloc` memory for this pointer and it is, as usual with `malloc` not `free`d at the end of scope. You need to do it yourself but this is probably less important for a global.

I'll just stop here. There is so much wrong. You shouldn't use `malloc` in C++. You shouldn't use plain arrays in C++. And you should avoid globals as much as possible have globals. You should rather state what you are trying to do, with code.

Comment: @hsalimi Unfortunately my crystal ball is defunct and I couldn't infer this from his question.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc`'s memory will remain valid until you `free` it. However, this is a hideously bad design. Technically, this is legal and correct. It is, however, definitely not the *right* way to do it. First, global variables are *bad*. If you have a design and it includes a global variable, think again until it doesn't. Second, you should use `new`, `delete` and a smart pointer, not `malloc` and `free`. Thirdly, just make it a member variable of the class?

Comment: @john, why? the OP does mention that it should be a class member accessible to member function, nothing about being across all *instances* of said class...

Comment: @Nim: Well I'm assuming he knows about member variables and he's trying a global variables as the only mechanism he knows to share data among different instances.

Comment: Whilst I don't disagree outright with anything you've said there @DeadMG, 'hideously bad design' and 'global variables are bad' are rather absolute. Global variables are widely misused, but not bad per se. Smart pointers could be really difficult with a beginner, but maybe if used exclusively over explicit 'raw' pointer types it would reduce the problems caused by not really 'getting' memory management.

Comment: @boycy: If you don't know how to use `malloc`, you sure as hell don't know how to use a global variable. People should be taught smart pointers immediately, and only go back to learning manual memory management if they need it for some specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you should avoid global variables unless absolutely no other solution is available (which IMHO shouldn't be the case ever if a software is well designed).

1. If by *global* you mean as member, like this

   class A
   {
   private:
       double N;
   };

then yes.

If by *global* you mean something like this (which AFAIK is correct concept for *global* variable)

```
double N;
class A
{
};
```

then you should avoid this and use the previous (use the variable as a class *member*).

1. Your example makes no sense since *double* already has a size. You need to use a pointer with *malloc()*, for example *double* N*. Also since you're programming on C++, use *new* instead. All memory allocated by either *new* (recommended) or *malloc()* (not recommended) stays reserved unless you manually free it (which you should not forget to do when that memory is no longer needed).

Comment: Hm, `std::cout` is a global variable, and that's not terrible design. I prefer a handy global over some complicated `System::Console::StandardOutputWriter::Instance()` any day...

Comment: Well I don't prefer it ^^ It might be easier and shorter to type, but that doesn't mean it's a better design IMHO. Btw I think more modern languages than C++ do not use such global variables anymore.
Anyway, a lot of things are flawed on OO paradigm. Like someone said: "I just wanted a banana, but I get the a banana, an ape holding it and a whole jungle behind it"

Comment: @m0skit0: Java's `System.out` is effectively a global variable, and that's more modern than C++...

Comment: @Kerrek: `cout` is not really a global variable, it's a process-local variable. @Oli: Java is notorious for terrible design and excessive pattern usage, so I wouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: @m0skit0 Neither does it imply bad design though. Can't say I've ever had any problem caused by cout and friends being global, though YMMV. Out of interest, have you had any issues due to that?

Comment: @DeadMG Unless I've missed something, in C++ terminology cout is indeed a global variable.

Comment: I think *cout* and the likes are a special case of global variable. Let's take for example a global pointer. While semantically they are the same, they generally differ functionally (how they're used). *cout* is I/O and thus used mainly for outputting data to the user. Generally you don't manipulate it too much, except for initialization (redirection, etc...). On the other hand, the global pointer is most likely heavily used throughout the code (that's why it was made global) and hinders code portability, reuse and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience as a programmer, I never instantiate a variable in a header file.
Rather, I can instantiate the variable in a C file, but EXTERN (in the header file) so that other classes can use it. But if you want to declare it, it should be fine.

And when you malloc you are saying N has this size. 
But if you haven't malloc it and you are trying to use it within a different method, then you will have a segmentation fault due to the fact that there is no allocated space for it (this is only for pointers and lists,arrays and etc. you dont need to do it for single data types.)

N can be instantiated anywhere, but it has to be instantiated before used.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, that is the right way.
2. If you are going to use dynamically allocated memory, you should declare N as "*double **" not "*double*". In addition, use "*new*" instead of "*malloc*" in C++. While you have not released N bu using "delete", it will be globally available, so it stays global, not in the scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the idiomatic way to construct and manage data members of classes in C++! Typically you would declare an object as follows:

```
class foo
{
public:
  foo() : N(0.) {}  // initialize N in the ctor
  // interface
private:
  // data
  double N;
};
```

Now all methods in `foo` can read/modify (depending on `const`ness) the member `N`. You don't need to manually manage the storage for `N`, it is managed as part of the instance of `foo`. You don't need a separate "global" variable unless you want *all instances* of `foo` and it's members to use the same `N`. Even then, it doesn't make sense for it to be dynamic.